# MySQL triggers to check data - how to call procedure and reference 'new'?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

With MySQL, I want to use before-insert and before-update triggers to check data, similar to the way check conditions work. I can code this easily enough, and it works, but since I need two triggers (insert + update) and the checking code is identical, I want to put it into a procedure. However, it seems that I can't use the "new" qualifier in a procedure--only in a trigger. Nor can it be passed as a parameter.

Any ideas how to do this? I really hate to have to duplicate the checking code in the two triggers.

(It's too bad the trigger syntax can't be something like "CREATE TRIGGER t BEFORE INSERT-OR-UPDATE ON ...".)

UPDATE: Here's a PHP function I wrote to create the two triggers without having to have two copies of the checking code. I'd still like to know if there's a pure MySQL way to do this without duplicating the checking code.

```
function add_trigger($table, $sql) {
    dbquery2("drop trigger if exists table_{$table}_trigger1");
    dbquery2("drop trigger if exists table_{$table}_trigger2");
    dbquery2("create trigger table_{$table}_trigger1 before insert on $table for each row begin $sql end");
    dbquery2("create trigger table_{$table}_trigger2 before update on $table for each row begin $sql end");
}
```

dbquery2 is my own function that calls mysqli::query.

UPDATE 2: Given that the SQL is going to be generated by PHP, here's an improved version that uses just one procedure. The ridiculously long parameter lists are generated by PHP from the information_schema, so their length and redundancy doesn't matter.

```
function add_trigger($table, $sql) {
    if ($result = dbquery2("select column_name, column_type from information_schema.columns where table_schema = 'cwadb_local' and table_name = '$table'")) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $cols .= ", new.{$row['column_name']}";
            $params .= ", {$row['column_name']} {$row['column_type']}";
        }
        $cols = substr($cols, 2); // remove extra ", " at front
        $params = substr($params, 2);
        $t1 = "create trigger table_{$table}_trigger1 before insert on $table for each row begin call check_table_{$table}($cols); end";
        $t2 = "create trigger table_{$table}_trigger2 before update on $table for each row begin call check_table_{$table}($cols); end";
        $proc = "create procedure check_table_{$table}($params) begin $sql end";
        dbquery2("drop procedure if exists check_table_{$table}"); // like mysqli::query, but throws exception on error
        dbquery2("drop trigger if exists table_{$table}_trigger1");
        dbquery2("drop trigger if exists table_{$table}_trigger2");
        dbquery2($t1);
        dbquery2($t2);
        dbquery2($proc);
        echo "<p>Success!";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm in the process of writing a PHP function, add_trigger, that adds a trigger to a database. It generates the SQL code to create the two triggers, and then executes it. That way there is only one copy of the checking code.